# Can anyone give me some hints to prove $\mathbb{E}${g(X)*$\mathbb{E}${X|Y}|Y}=$\mathbb{E}${g(X)*X|Y}?

Tags: expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Can anyone give me some hints on the following proof?

$\mathbb{E}${g(X)*$\mathbb{E}${X|Y}|Y}=$\mathbb{E}${g(X)*X|Y}

I only know g(.) is a convex function. I am not good at math. Thank you in advance!

If there is no solution, can I prove that $\ge$ holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is not true.
Suppose $\xi_1, \xi_2$ are i.i.d. standard normal distributed and define $Y := \xi_1$ and $X := \xi_1 + \xi_2$.
Consider $g(x) := x$.
Then
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[g(X) X \, \middle\vert \, Y \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[X^2 \, \middle\vert \, Y \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[\xi_1^2 + 2\xi_1 \xi_2 + \xi_2^2 \, \middle\vert \, \xi_1 \right]
= \xi_1^2 + 2 \mathbb{E}[\xi_1]\xi_2 + \mathbb{E}[\xi_2^2]\\
= \xi_2^2 + 1,
$$ but
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X \, \middle\vert \, Y \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[\xi_1 + \xi_2 \, \middle\vert \, \xi_1 \right]
= \xi_1 + \mathbb{E}[\xi_2] = \xi_1,
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ g(X) \mathbb{E}[X \vert Y] \, \middle\vert \, Y\right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[(\xi_1 + \xi_2)\xi_1 \, \middle\vert \, \xi_1 \right]
= \xi_1^2.
$$.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It helps a lot!